# How Do I Add TypeScript to a SvelteKit Handle Function in Hooks?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am currently using the following in my `hooks.ts` file in a SvelteKit app:

```
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  console.log(event.locals) //<-- Works fine
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use types on the `event` and `resolve` parameters. As far as I can tell, `event` works like this:

```
import type { RequestEvent } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export async function handle(event: RequestEvent, resolve: ???){
  ...
}
```

But I can't figure out how to type the `resolve` parameter. The [docs here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#sveltejs-kit-handle) show this:

```js
interface Handle {
  (input: {
    event: RequestEvent;
    resolve(
      event: RequestEvent,
      opts?: ResolveOptions
    ): MaybePromise<Response>;
  }): MaybePromise<Response>;
}
```

From my limited TypeScript knowledge, it looks like `resolve` is a function with two parameters that returns a promise. But how do I write that out in the `handle` function declaration?

Comment: Your attempt to type the arguments would not work because the function only has one argument with multiple properties. If an argument contains curly braces that means it is immediately being destructured.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your question is (or should be ): "How do I tell TypeScript that my function is of type `Handle`?".

I think the simplest way would be to create a variable out of the function so you can easily type it.

```
export const handle: Handle = async function ({ event, resolve }) {
  console.log(event.locals);
}
```

Notice that you don't need to type `event` or `resolve` separately, TS already knows about your function's argument and return type. It will flag your existing implementation because it's not returning a `MaybePromise<Response>`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to typing the function as a whole, which is convenient in that it types arguments and return type, you can type those separately and retain the `export async function` syntax.

The argument type does not have a name, though, so you need to extract it manually from `Handle`. Note that there actually is only one argument, which is being destructured. E.g.

```js
// Maybe export this from elsewhere to not repeat it
type HandleParams = Parameters<Handle>[0];

export async function handle({ event, resolve }: HandleParams) : Promise<Response> {
    // ...
}
```

The original return type uses `MaybePromise<T>` to allow synchronous and async returns. You can just only use `Promise` if the function is actually `async`.

There also is another helper type like `Parameters` that would allow you to extract the return type generically from `Handle`:

```js
type HandleResult = ReturnType<Handle>;
```

Comment: I thought about suggesting something like this but you have to duplicate the return type anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add 'satisfies Handle' to your function you'll get the 'any' warnings to go away.

```
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle = (async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  if (event.url.pathname.startsWith('/custom')) {
    return new Response('custom response');
  }

  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
}) satisfies Handle;
```

Reference: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks

For that above link, be sure to turn on TypeScript to see the correct examples:

[image]

Comment: Why use `satisfies` instead of just typing it [as I suggested in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72843974/227299)? Side note: try not to start an answer with "I think", if you post an answer,  you should be fairly confident. "I think" is OK for comments.

Comment: I was giving the example verbatim as found in the SvelteKit documentation. I'll play around with this later and see if there's any benefit to using 'satisfies'. Thanks for your side note, but do you realize your answer starts with "I think"?

Comment: That is pretty funny. However, they are two very different cases of "I think". I'm not saying "I think this will solve your problem".  You are saying you think but you are not sure if your answer is correct. I'm saying "I think your question is misguided and here's why". I'm politely rephrasing their question more accurately.

Comment: I didn't write the example, so I cannot fully speak as why they wrote it as such... but I would guess it's because they wanted to demonstrate that shape needed to match that type, but that it didn't need to necessarily be of that type.